# How to assign a param to a method in Reason

Tags: ocaml, reason

I have the following abstractFactory class:

```
class virtual virtualProductA = {
  pub virtual methodA: string;
};

class virtual virtualProductB = {
  pub virtual methodB: int;
};

class virtual abstractFactory = {
  pub virtual createProductA : virtualProductA;
  pub virtual createProductB : virtualProductB;
};
```

In particular, I would like to specify that the abstractFactory `createProductA` method has an optional param, that can be of any type.

Something along the lines of the following: 
`pub virtual createProductA (param?:any) : virtualProductA;`

However, the above does not compile properly.

Any suggestions as to proper syntax is more than greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this optional parameter? Also, things like abstractFactories are extremely unidiomatic in OCaml. What is your end-goal ?

Comment: It is more for learning purposes. After learning OCaml, i figure the best way to delve deep into the language is to code something familiar with i.e. OOP. Then take what I've learn and apply that to functional programming.

Comment: Purpose of Param is allow user to potentially add in a string, number, or object to method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**: I'm using OCaml. The Reason examples are translated using Try Reason.

I'm not sure I got your question right, but here are my thoughts on this.

If you want to give an argument to the constructor of your class `virtualProductA`, here the syntax.

### OCaml

```
class virtual virtualProductA my_object = object
  val value : 'a = my_object
  method virtual  methodA : string
end
```

### Reason

```
class virtual virtualProductA my_object => {
  as _;
  val value: 'a = my_object;
  pub virtual methodA: string;
};
```

In your abstract factory, the method `createProductA` now takes an argument and is polymorphic.

### OCaml

```
class virtual abstractFactory = object
  method virtual createProductA : 'a. 'a -> virtualProductA
  method virtual createProductB : virtualProductB
end
```

### Reason

```
class virtual abstractFactory = {
  as _;
  pub virtual createProductA: 'a. 'a => virtualProductA;
  pub virtual createProductB: virtualProductB;
};
```

The type quantifier `'a.` means *"for all types `'a`, ..."*. It is used to tell the compiler "This is not a type parameter, this is merely a polymorphic method".

---

On second thought, you will probably want to make `virtualProductA` generic, here's the syntax for that:

### OCaml

```
class virtual ['a] virtualProductA my_object = object
  val value : 'a = my_object
  method value = value (* type 'a is inferred here, no need to over-annotate *)
  method virtual methodA : string
end
```

### Reason

```
class virtual virtualProductA 'a my_object => {
  as _;
  val value: 'a = my_object;
  pub value = value;  /* type 'a is inferred here, no need to over-annotate */
  pub virtual methodA: string;
};
```